# How to create column that will autogenerate the serial number for Each row of a Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I have a Gridview with a list of Items. I want to show the Serial Number in One Column of a GridView like 1 2 3 4 5.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using `Container.DataItemIndex` in GridView. It will display serial numbers as above mentioned.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNo.">
     <itemtemplate>
          <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>                                                    
     </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding this data to the source you are using to bind to the GridView. So If you have a `ICollection<Product>` that you are binding to the GridView, add the Serial number to the product class.

Alternatively, you could turn the `ICollection<Product>` into a `Dictionary<int, Product>` and bind the key to the Serial number column.

It's difficult to know what would suit without knowing how you are biding your data.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Template field inside the tag Columns. You will get AutoGenerate SNo.

For More Information see the below link

[How to create autogenerate serial number column in GridView](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/how-to-create-autogenerate-serial-number-column-in-gridview.aspx?Id=74)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
         CellPadding="5" Style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); width: 50%;">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way...

```
 <ItemTemplate>                  
    <%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %> 
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

Googling for [serial number column gridview](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=serial+number+column+gridview&aq=f&aqi=g-b1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d51b48cd8e832d5c&biw=1440&bih=694) will give you millions of results that discuss the same thing. Read the articles/tutorials/discussion and implement it.
Please do Google before you ask.

Comment: That is true, but ultimately Google will point to results like this article so we have a responsibility to answer the question.

Comment: How does this add any value as an answer

Comment: What's the point discussing the same thing that has already been discussed thousands of time. IMHO if doing a simple Google search can help you find the answer then doing that is worth it instead of putting your time to writing a question and waiting for the replies.